# How to manage two grid containers in godot so you can see their contents

Tags: godot

[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dnk1nrmsxyedfdb/Su3%20Version%202.zip?dl=0)
Here is the whole GODOT Project

I have one grid container set at 0,0 with  5000,5000 min size with scaling of 1.7 and it shows its buttons well.  Another grid container set at 5000,0 with 2000,2000 min size with scaling 1.7 and it definitely attaches its buttons. They even appeared once correctly with different grid container coordinates and a bit low. The remote viewer shows they have been created but with the settings are currently invisible. Is there some trick to get them to show? All buttons are created by script. Also can't see both grid container at the same time- how to do that?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "see both grid container at the same time" but a couple things comes to mind: 1. You can select multiple nodes in the scene tree (with Ctrl or Shift and click). 2. You can run code in the editor (see [Running Code in the editor](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/misc/running_code_in_the_editor.html)).

Comment: I can click on each node but can't see them both on Main to compare their grid positions